# apt-get update cannot connect to servers when using house modem

Tags: networking, apt

Currently, with a vanilla installation of **Ubuntu 17.10**, when I am connected to my house modem, `apt-get update` cannot connect to the servers (even though the internet works fine). 
However, when I use my phone's hotspot, it works just fine.

We recently got a new modem in the house, the Motorola MB7621, maybe that has something to do with the problem.

This is the output of **`ifconfig`** in case it helps:

[image: ifconfig output]

NOTE: I believe the problem has something to do with ipv6 or the network in general, but do not know how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Are you able to ping a website just fine or access the internet at all through the modem or is is just apt-get?